# validation not working in email template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have used JavaScript to validate form using id #mycontactform but it is not working.
then i used required but it also not working. I spent more time behind this but still not get success.

Here is the JavaScript i tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('#mycontactform').submit()
    $('#mycontactform').submit(function() {
        $.post('send.php', $('#mycontactform').serialize(),  function(response) {
            $('#success').html(response);
          //$('#success').hide('slow');
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert('Information Send Successfully');
            }, 1000);
            $('#submit').css('background','green');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is HTML:

```
<form id='mycontactform' action='send.php' method='post'>
    <select id='time' name='time' style='text-align:center;' required>
        <option value=''>&nbsp;&nbsp;-- select --&nbsp;</option>
        <option value='this week'>this week</option>
        <option value='next week'>next week</option>
        <option value='no rush'>no rush</option>
    </select>

    <select id='people' name='people' style='text-align:center;' required>
        <option value=''>&nbsp;&nbsp;-- select --&nbsp;</option>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
        <option value='5'>5</option>
    </select>

    <label for='radio3'>Yes</label>
    <input type='radio' id='radio3' name='obstacles' value='yes' checked>

    <label for='radio4'>No</label>
    <input type='radio' id='radio4' name='obstacles' value='no'>
</form>
```

Here is PHP:

```
<?php
$obstacles = $_POST['obstacles'];
$people = $_POST['people'];
$tim = $_POST['time'];
$to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$from = $email;
$subject = 'Domestic & Commercial Gutter cleaning Replies From Email';
$body = "Obstacles : <strong>$obstacles</strong><br>
People Required : <strong>$people</strong><br>
Time required : <strong>$tim</strong><br>
";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from";
$ok = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if($ok)
echo '1';
else
echo '0';
?>
```

Please suggest me helpful solution. All possible ways like using Ajax, make JavaScript working, or any other way.

Comment: Can you show your JavaScript code?

Comment: Did you actually prevent the form from being submitted in your javascript code so you can check first?

Comment: I just used HTML 5 validation that is "required" and it was working but after getting it in gmail it is not working.

Comment: then your problem may lie on your php code that can't send the e-mail well

Comment: please check the code, i added php and JavaScript i tried both.

Comment: hi, have you check the code ?

Comment: Try to figure out if the values are passed correctly, remove the return false to actually go to the '.php' page you have and echo the first 3 values to see them. If everything is ok then something goes wrong with the email data.

Comment: @Θεόφιλος Μουρατίδης He can do this using developer tools on FF or Chrome and see the Network Response

Answer (score 0):

Your html code does not have a submit button.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Data">
```